# xml parsed image won't work in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, rss, nsxmlparser

I have successfully parsed the name and it shows up in the `cell.textLabel.text` but the image on the other hand doesn't show up. It works when I type the name of a local image as the string but when i connect it to the parsed image string it doesn't show. Thoughts on why this is? thanks.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    [cell setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"Name"]];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18];
    NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"Image"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:storyLink];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *background = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = background;
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic

  }


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([stories count] == 0) {
        NSString * path = @"http://travisupload.weebly.com/uploads/9/0/0/1/9001440/sports.xml";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    }

    cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}




- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");

}

- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    // here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error
    // this may be necessary only for the toolchain
    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [rssParser parse];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Sport"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentImage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Sport"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentName forKey:@"Name"];
        [item setObject:currentImage forKey:@"Image"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
        [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];


        [stories addObject:[item copy]];
        NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentName);
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
        [currentName appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Image"]) {
        [currentImage appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate appendString:string];
    }


}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

    NSLog(@"all done!");
    NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
    [newsTable reloadData];
}





- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [currentElement release];
    [rssParser release];
    [stories release];
    [item release];
    [currentName release];
    [currentDate release];
    [currentSummary release];
    [currentImage release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Why are you making a synchronous network call on the main thread ? NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

Comment: Also, have you checked the results of the line where you set data to the contents of the URL? You should verify that the URL is actually valid, and that you are actually successfully getting the data you expect.

Comment: Also, initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code!!

```
NSString *imageStr = [imageURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *trimmedString = [imageStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *string1=[trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string1];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image = newImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not download image on main thread. Try [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), asynchronous image downloader with cache support with an UIImageView category.